# A 2-page paper on a lower bound of Ramsey number

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, graph-theory, ramsey-theory

I'm looking for a 2-page paper on a lower bound of Ramsey number $R(a,b)$ for some constants $a$ and $b$. The paper was published in 80s or 90s. I googled it for a few days, but I cannot find the paper.

The paper improves the lower bound of $R(a,b)$ to $n + 1$ by constructing a graph with $n$ vertices without $K_a$ in one color (red) nor $K_b$ in the other color (blue). IIRC $20 < n < 30$. It constructs the graph in the following steps:

- Step 1. Place $n$ vertices on a circle.
- Step 2. If $u, v \in V$ has odd number of vertices between them along the circle, color $uv \in E$ to one color (red). Otherwise, color $uv$ to the other color (blue).
- Step 3. There is a list of a dozen of edges to change the color.

Can anyone help me to find this paper?

Comment: Memory is a fickle friend, it something something in the end.

Comment: To me, most of this sounds like Exoo, "A Lower Bound For R(5,5)", except for Step 2.

Comment: Please use a high-level tag like "co.combinatorics". I added this tag now.

Answer (score 4):

The methodology you are looking for is referred as "cyclic Ramsey graphs", or "circulant coloring". You could also look at [Distance Ramsey number](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/266960583_Distance_Ramsey_numbers), a generalization of circulant coloring.

In the 1983 article "[A survey of bounds for classical Ramsey numbers](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1002/jgt.3190070105)", the authors, Chung and Grinstead state the following, (page 6 after Theorem 2.4).

[image: Excerpt from Chung and Grinstead - A survey of bounds for classical Ramsey numbers]

The short cited article [Greenwood and Gleason - Combinatorial relations and chromatic graphs](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/canadian-journal-of-mathematics/article/combinatorial-relations-and-chromatic-graphs/BF0DEBC881488344266BCD77CBBCD86B) is older than you request, but it should be the correct methodology. In there the author proved that $n(3,5)>13$ and some other inequalities with this methodology. It might not be the exact one you were looking for but it should allow you to find the correct one.

[image: Excerpt from Greenwood and Gleason - Combinatorial relations and chromatic graphs]

In case you don't know it, Radziszowski maintains a [survey](https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/DS1) on "Small Ramsey numbers" that probably contains the article you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I might have found it, let me know if it's the right paper or not:
[image]

Edited after the comment below: there is at least another one paper potentially relevant: [Guldan - New lower bounds of some diagonal Ramsey numbers](https://www.sciencegate.app/app/document/download/10.1002/jgt.3190070118).

Comment: For the readers' convenience, here is the link: https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82482174.pdf, but the proof therein does not look entirely as the OP says (but maybe that's just a memory issue).

Comment: I think 2 pages papers on the subject published between 1980 and 1999 must not be that common.